# Spring Boot basic authentication to 3rd party

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot to login to an external program using its basic authentication. That authentication exists of giving username + password and use Base64 to encode the header. After this I can use a call + header (containing password and username) to retrieve data.

Is there a simple way in Spring Boot to temporary save that header? And after the user is done, he/she can simply remove that header?
Otherwise the user has to keep giving username+password for every call to the API.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "url";

        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders("mail", "password");

        ResponseEntity<JsonSearchResponse> response = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<JsonSearchResponse>(headers), JsonSearchResponse.class);

        JsonSearchResponse obj = response.getBody();

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static HttpHeaders createHeaders(String username, String password) {
        return new HttpHeaders() {{
            String auth = username + ":" + password;
            byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
            String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
            set("Authorization", authHeader);
        }};
    }
}
```

In the end I'm going to put this code in a different class. But just prototyping at the moment.
The application is going to be a web application. Using a database. I'm also going to use Thymeleaf. 
All users use the same backend. As it is usually the case with web applications.

Comment: You generally aren't using *Boot* to use the external service--Boot configures your Spring context, and it may include any number of other Spring components. In this case, it's likely that you're using RestTemplate--please show whatever code you have. It's also important to know (it's not clear) whether this is a pass-through on a per-session basis or whether all users use the same backend connection (like is common with an application database).

Comment: @chrylis added some code. All users are going to use this application. So save it per user if possible.

Comment: I guess you can store it in each users session in your application, and then just retrieve it from there when calling the external system?